# Ordering of Mnesia events

Tags: events, erlang, mnesia, subscribe

We’re developing an application where multiple processes on different nodes in a distributed system subscribe to mnesia events. The table is written to from one single process on one of the nodes.

However uncertainty has arose about if we can be sure to receive the events in the same order as operations on the table.

E.g:

```
mnesia:delete(tab1, SomeRec),
mnesia:write(tab1, SomeOtherRec)
```

If we sometimes get the delete event after the write event our design would not work and we would have to create some other kind of notification mechanism.

Also, how about operations on different tables (from the same process)?

```
mnesia:write(tab1, SomeRec),
mnesia:write(tab2, SomeOtherRec)
```

Can we be sure to always get the event from tab1 before the one from tab2? On all processes and all nodes?

Comment: Somehow I get the impression you are trying to use the mnesia events for something better done different. Can't put my finger on it why however.  Can you elaborate what exactly you want to do with these table events?

Comment: Thats totally possible. But it would be be interesting to get this sorted out anyway.

Answer (score 1):

For Erlang as a whole, the sending of messages from a process `A` to a process `B` is guaranteed to always be in order.

However, for messages between more than two processes, you can not guarantee that messages sent from `A` to `B` will arrive before messages sent from `C` to `B`, even if `A`'s messages were globally sent first. The scheduler, network latency or network problems (especially if `A` and `C` aren't on the same node) might be good examples of why such guarantees are hard to give.

If all your events are sent from the same process, ordering can be a sure thing. Otherwise, you can't trust the events' order.

As for mnesia events, They're all managed in `mnesia_subscr.erl`, which is a single gen_server taking charge of forwarding all events for a node, no matter the table. This should thus adhere to the `A` to `B` principle and guarantee ordered events.

Comment: I understand that the messages between processes are always in order. But do mnesia always send the messages in the order that the operations occur on the calling process? E.g. if a table is locked for writing when mnesia:write is called, can this cause the event to be delayed and some other event to be sent first?

Comment: That would depend on how you implement your event sending. Is it done from within the transaction, once it's complete, etc.? As far as I know, you should never do things with side effects from inside a transaction because it could be retried a few times.

Comment: @IGTA: Lii was talking about mnmesia table events, so its a question also about how these are implemented. Are these sent by a single internal process (per node?, per Table?)

Comment: Ah sorry, I didn't get you right. The subscriber events are managed in 'mnesia_subscr.erl', which is implemented as a gen_server. So yes, all messages are coming from the same process for that given node, no matter what table. I'll edit my answer to add this info.

Comment: That sounds somewhat reassuring. "This should thus adhere..." is about as long as we got with problem, but its good to hear that someone else makes the same analysis.

Comment: The questions is I guess, does mnesia send the events to the mnesia_subscr gen_server in the expected order under all conditions?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether mnesia will do what you want by default, but assuming that it doesn't then perhaps you need to start looking at the use of distributed consensus algorithms such as [Paxos](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paxos_algorithm)? There is an implementation in the form of [lib_paxos](http://libpaxos.sourceforge.net/), a GPL licensed open source library.

Needless to say, this will impact your performance but ensure consistency.

Comment: Unfortunately that is not an option. Either mnesia behaves or we have to create our own notification mechanism.

Comment: yep - I was (kinda) suggesting that Paxos is a robust way to do that in a distributed env...

Answer (score 0):

Paxos is the solution you are looking for. Make the selection of accepted values is a Max of earlier accepted proposals. This will create a sequence you can use to order your instructions.